# What characters dont get Encoded?

Tags: c#, web-services, api, urlencode, encode

So i am building a WebAPI in C# and when I encode my string using

Uri.EscapeDataString(String)

some characters are not encoded like !.

I was curious if there was a list of what all those characters are that don't get encoded are
because the user can pass just about anything. So I can create an exception and manually encode them myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) page of the Uri.EscapeDataString Method says:

> By default, the EscapeDataString
>   method converts all characters except
>   for RFC 2396 unreserved characters to
>   their hexadecimal representation.

The [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) says in Chapter 2.3. Unreserved Characters:

```
  unreserved  = alphanum | mark

  mark        = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"
```